# Firebreath - cannot inject plugin

Tags: javascript, firebreath

I am developing Web application using Angular - In order to be able to work with chrome and IE11, I am using Firebreath to hide the ActiveX. I am trying to inject the html - however the pluging isnt created

```
function activate() {
        var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        objNode = document.createElement("object");
        objNode.setAttribute("id", 'plugin0');
        objNode.setAttribute("type", "application/x-nvplayer");
        headElement.appendChild(objNode);
    }
```

when I take this code - and paste it into static html file - all works

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things

1. Don't set "type" until after it's in the DOM
2. You haven't showed us how to put this in the angular code, but most of the time an angular directive is not in the page until some time after the link function completes; again, don't set the type until after it's in the page.
3. There is a partial fix for angular support in the firebreath master branch; make sure you're on that, as it does seem to help with some issues, though not all.

Comment: thanks, the issue was the VS was in admin, and i has to mark the user machine in the config